# [UWP]Custom control visualstate not work

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I create a custom control in my windows 10 UWP app called `CustomControl1`

```
public sealed class CustomControl1 : ButtonBase
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
    }
}
```

And the default style in `Generic.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomControl1">
                <Border>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="This is a text block"/>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="textBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="textBlock.TextBlock" Value="Blue"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is the TextBlock's foreground don't change to `Red` when mouse over nor change to `Blue` when pressed. But if i change `CustomControl1`'s base class to `Button` it works fine.

```
public sealed class CustomControl1 : Button
{
    public CustomControl1()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
    }
}
```

What's different between the two cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Button has the visual states you used, and ButtonBase doesn't.
So when you write that template for ButtonBase, the control itself doesn't activate any visual states and therefore your text color doesn't change. Button on the other hand does, and color changes.

Comment: I remember all the `Control` have MouseOver/Pressed state in WPF/Silverlight, why microsoft remove it from uwp?